# DRF: Cannot POST or create a new object through admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to create a new object through the admin interface:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'ImproperlyConfigured' and 'tuple'

I have the following models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = 'user'

class Address(models.Model):
    """Address contains information about location. Address can be own by any
    kind of model."""
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    owner = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

    CATEGORIES = Choices('billing', 'shipping')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=16)
    address_1 = models.CharField("address line 1", max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField("address line 2", max_length=128, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state_province = models.CharField('state/province', max_length=128)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'{self.address_1}, {self.city}, {self.state_province}, '
            f'{self.country.name}, {self.zip_code}'
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

class Company(Group):
    """An abstract base class that inherits Group."""
    addresses = GenericRelation(Address)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='%(class)ss',
                              related_query_name='%(class)s')
    logo = CloudinaryField('image',
                           default='your_logo_here',
                           null=True,
                           blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('description', max_length=3000, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.URLField('facebook url', blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField('twitter url', blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.URLField('instagram url', blank=True)
    pinterest_url = models.URLField('pinterest url', blank=True)
    portfolio_url = models.URLField('portfolio url',  blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField('phone number', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('id',)


class Brand(Company):
    """A Brand can have multiple members."""
```

These are my serializers:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    brands = HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='brand-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'url',
            'username',
            'email',
            'brands',
        )

class AddressSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = GenericRelatedField({
        Brand: HyperlinkedRelatedField(
            queryset=Brand.objects.all(),
            view_name='brand-detail',
        )
    })

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = (
            'url',
            'category',
            'address_1',
            'address_2',
            'city',
            'state_province',
            'country',
            'zip_code',
            'owner',
        )


class BrandSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    addresses = HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,
                                        read_only=True,
                                        view_name='address-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = (
            'url',
            'owner',
            'logo',
            'description',
            'facebook_url',
            'twitter_url',
            'instagram_url',
            'pinterest_url',
            'portfolio_url',
            'phone_number',
            'addresses',
        )
```

This is how I configured the urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', CustomUserViewSet)
router.register('addresses', AddressViewSet)
router.register('brands', BrandViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

I can access `http://localhost:8000/api/addresses/`, and I have the following form:

[image]

The problem is when I try to POST to create a new object. I am getting that error I have described, and it seems because I am not passing properly the owner (actually I have no idea how to pass an object here, should I use a JSON or how).

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I solve this error because I am also trying to test the POST method, and it was when I realized this was not working?
2. Is there any way to include the fields of a `GenericForeignKey` in that form?

This is my traceback:

```
File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/generic_relations/serializers.py" in to_internal_value
  39.             serializer = self.get_deserializer_for_data(data)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/generic_relations/serializers.py" in get_deserializer_for_data
  75.                 'Could not determine a valid serializer for value %r.' % value)

During handling of the above exception (Could not determine a valid serializer for value ''.), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_internal_value
  488.                 validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in run_validation
  536.         value = self.to_internal_value(data)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/generic_relations/serializers.py" in to_internal_value
  41.             raise ValidationError(e)

During handling of the above exception (["Could not determine a valid serializer for value ''."]), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_error_detail
  240.         error_dict = exc_info.error_dict

During handling of the above exception ('ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_dict'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  20.         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
  236.                 self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in run_validation
  434.         value = self.to_internal_value(data)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_internal_value
  494.                 errors[field.field_name] = get_error_detail(exc)

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_error_detail
  245.             for error in exc_info.error_list]

File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/na-ERB0uoVd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in <listcomp>
  245.             for error in exc_info.error_list]

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/addresses/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'ImproperlyConfigured' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD, I just added it.

Comment: try to comment out the **`__str__()`** method of **`Address`** model and try again

Comment: @JPG, I did it, and I am still getting the same error. I wonder why you are suggesting that since the `__str__` method is just a string representation.

Comment: If I do a web search for 'ImproperlyConfigured' I find a lot of results referencing 'ImproperlyConfigured' and wsgi.  How are you running your server?

Comment: @RedCricket, I am just running it by `python manage.py runserver` as usual.

Comment: Instead of using https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations can you try with https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships? FYI: I am not an expert in this, so just guessing

Comment: What is the POST data that is being passed in the request ?

Answer (score 0):

If add read_only=True like the following:

```
owner = GenericRelatedField({
    Brand: HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Brand.objects.all(),
        view_name='brand-detail',
    )
}, read_only=True)
```

the error will disappear. But then you need to write your
own create() method in the same serializer with serialization of owner to account for how
you would like to save owner.